# About real time statistics oracle 19c only for particular table

Tags: oracle, performance-testing, query-performance, database-administration, oracle19c

Reg Real-Time statistics which extends online statistics gathering(12c) to also include conventional DML statements.
Real-time statistics helps the optimizer generate more optimal plans.Whereas bulk load operations gather all necessary statistics, real-time statistics augment rather than replace traditional statistics.

Oracle introduced new parameters

`_optimizer_gather_stats_on_conventional_dml` and `_optimizer_use_stats_on_conventional_dml` which are true by default and
`_optimizer_stats_on_conventional_dml_sample_rate` at 100%

How does real time statistics works?

By default the `_optimizer_gather_stats_on_conventional_dml` is true so its automatically kicks off

When a DML operation is currently modifying a table (conventional), Oracle Database dynamically computes values for the most essential statistics if the above parameter is on.

Consider a example of table that is having lot of inserts and rows are increasing. Real-time statistics keep track of the increasing row count as rows are being inserted. If the optimizer performs a hard parse of a new query, then the optimizer can use the real-time statistics to obtain a more accurate cost estimate.

`USER_TAB_COL_STATISTICS` and `USER_TAB_STATISITICS` has columns NOTES tell real time statistics have been used. "STATS_ON_CONVENTIONAL_DML".

Execution Plan shows

```
|Id| Operation                        | Name|Rows|Bytes|Cost (%CPU)|Time| Pstart|Pstop|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0| INSERT STATEMENT                 |     |    |     |910 (100)|        |     |     |
| 1|  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL         |SALES|    |     |         |        |     |     |
| 2|   OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING |     |918K|  25M|910   (2)|00:00:01|     |     |
| 3|    PARTITION RANGE ALL           |     |918K|  25M|910   (2)|00:00:01|   1 |  28 |
| 4|     TABLE ACCESS FULL            |SALES|918K|  25M|910   (2)|00:00:01|   1 |  28 |

Also the explain plan in the query used will tell in note section
    Note

    -----
    - dynamic statistics used: stats for conventional DML
```

`LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL` and `OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING` are the new parameters that have been added to the explain plan for this new feature.

Can we apply real-time statistics only for a particular set of tables? if yes, how?

We know getting real time statistics for any dml operation thats occurring for more than 100k rows is very costly operation

I tried finding out the way, but was not successful

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic statistics and real-time statistics are different.

Note that `OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING` is actually a 12.1 execution plan operation that is not related to real-time statistics according to 
[Mike Dietrich blog](https://mikedietrichde.com/2015/10/06/new-in-oracle-12c-_optimizer_gather_stats_on_load/). It looks like that 12.1 online statistics feature has been modified in 19c for Exadata and renamed real-time statistics.

Real-time statistics are only available on Exadata according to the [licensing guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-0F9EB85D-4610-4EDF-89C2-4916A0E7AC87): you cannot have real-time statistics on usual Entreprise Edition databases.

Do you have an Exadata system available ? If no you cannot test this feature.

Comment: Even if i dont have Exadataa system avaailable, we can alter using `alter system set “_exadata_feature_on”=true scope=spfile;` . Here my questiuon is can we use Real-time statistics  only for single table, i dont want to implement this for my whole database schema

Comment: OK you can test Exadata features with this undocumented parameter. And it's possible that some new 12.1 related features have been renamed and modified in 19 version. However according to the documentation real-time statistics is an automatic feature. There is a hint `NO_GATHER_OPTIMIZER_STATISTICS` to disable it for a specific query but I have not found any hint to enable it at query or table level and no DBMS_STATS feature to enable it at table level.

Comment: I have modified my answer about online statistics and real-time statistics features.

Comment: Yes, i also found the same, but in production environment we have 1000s of table, we cant modify insert, delete, update query with this hint `NO_GATHER_OPTIMIZER_STATISTICS` for all the tables manually. So, is there any other way where we can mention the table names, so only for those tables this new feature can be applied

Comment: If you have really a production issue with this Exadata feature you should work with Oracle support. And you should even work more with Oracle Support if you want to use undocumented parameters (you are not supposed to work with undocumented paramers in production without agreement of Oracle support otherwise your system may not be supported by Oracle). Sorry but I cannot help more.

Comment: If you use “_exadata_feature_on”=true on a production non exadata system, you're in big trouble licensing wise. And if support finds it out, you're in deeper trouble. As for your question, you can try locking the table statistics (I did not test).